# Why does this keep going to the elif block?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, logical-operators

Shouldn't it check the first if statement and go to black_room if donate_money = 0 and spend_money is 20?

```
def white_room():
    spend_money = raw_input("How much money have you spent?")
    donate_money = raw_input("How much money have you donated?")

    if (donate_money <= 0 and spend_money > 10): 
        print "You go to the black room!!"
        black_room()
    elif (donate_money > 0 and spend_money > 10):
        print donate_money
        print spend_money
        print "You can stay here..."
        white_room()
    else:
        print "You can live in the silver room forever"
```

Comment: Was going to answer but also you have to do int(spend_money) and int(donate_money) to do a numerical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Change `raw_input` to just `input`, see [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers-in-python) for details

```
spend_money = input("How much money have you spent?")
donate_money = input("How much money have you donated?")
```